# In C# what if the app pool is reset before the response of an async/await call returns?

Tags: c#, iis

I have some async code that is running in a web api, therefore managed by IIS.  Since the app pool is prone to getting restarted, what will happen if I make the async call, then the app pool is restarted before the response comes back from the async call?

I'm assuming that, since the memory of the app pool will get wiped, the response will never get processed.  Is that correct?  If so, does C# have some kind of mechanism I can use to make sure the response is still processed, even if the app pool has been reset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your await chain is awaited all the way up to your controller it does not reset the app pool on you, it acts the same as any other request that has not completed yet and will keep the app pool alive as long as it would have any synchronous request.

If you are talking about a "fire and forget" task that does not block the controller from completing then you need to use some kind of library to offload the work off of IIS or to have the work re-tried if it was canceled. Personally I like to use [hangfire.io](https://www.hangfire.io/), but here is [a list of some other options](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) for fire and forget tasks.